# Losing WebElement context inside for loop ? Why?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to access child WebElements **(img and p tags)** of a parent WebElement `<div class="post">` inside a `for` loop in that way.

```
self.posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='post']")

for post in self.posts:
    self.image = post.find_element_by_xpath(".//a/img")
    str = self.image.get_attribute("src").replace("b.", ".")

    self.title = post.find_element_by_xpath(".//div/p")
    self.title. # <<<<<------- Has no attributes or functions
```

Please note that I have used relative XPATH paths to access the child WebElements that refers to his parent `post` (.//a/img and .//div/p)

I can get the WebElement object context for `self.image`, it has all of the WebElement attributes. As you can see I can use `self.image.get_attribute()`

But then, when I'm  inside the loop, and try to instantiate the `post` variable to `self.title`, that variable does not have any attribute and my intellisense says **"no suggestions"**

My doubt is, why... Why I can use the `post` referente to instantiate a WebElement object `self.image` but I can't then do the same with `self.title`

Comment: Is this purely an issue with *code completion* ("my intellisense") or is it that your Selenium code is not *executing* in the way you want? There's a significant difference between the two problems. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @Louis If as stated, the first time intellisense was working fine inside the loop. I believe in that the second time its working too and the issue comes from de language domain or my inexperience in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awwhnn ¬¬ I feel stupid...

@Louis it was an intellisense issue. You're correct. No matter what intellisense was saying... I'll upvote your comment to give you kudos, since it was helpfull for me. ThankYou !

It works:

```
self.posts = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='post']")

for post in self.posts:
    self.image = post.find_element_by_xpath(".//a/img")
    str = self.image.get_attribute("src").replace("b.", ".")

    self.title = post.find_element_by_xpath(".//div/p")
    print(self.title.text)
```

Anyway, I have learnt that lesson...